# Music folder appearing twice on Dash

Tags: 11.10, unity, unity-dash, directory, duplicate-files

I installed 11.10 this week and, so far, this little detail have been bugging me. Since I moved my old audio files from a flash drive to the music folder, the music folder itself appears twice in the Dash, under the "search files".
I know that it has something to do with the bookmarks of the Home Folder, since I had similar problem once, but the bookmarks are okay (Music folder shows only once there). I'm sure I don't have two music folders, so why are two folders, both linking to the same path, appearing side-by-side in Dash? How do I remove one of them?

Answer (score 3):

I had a folder I used often to store a bunch of documents. I decided to move it, and then add the new location to my shortcuts list in the file browser. Now both folders show up and the broken link appears first.

The problem was in the bookmarks section of the file browser.

1. Go to `Bookmarks ▸ Edit bookmarks` in the file browser menu
2. Find the older link that you want to get rid of and remove it.

Unfortunately it didn't show up in the sidebar in the file browser after it became a dead link, so I figured it was a problem with some other indexing software in use.